# Identify Messages using Message API Android

Tags: android, wear-os

I have probably a simple question but has me stumped. For my Android Wear  application, I have two sensors working (step counter and heartrate).The wear app then sends these values back to the mobile application. I am sending them using the Message API. My stepcount sendMessage() and heartrate sendMessage() method look the same. Here is my heartrate sendMessage method.

```
private void sendMessageToHandheld(final String message) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
            return;

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"sending a message to handheld: "+message);

        // use the api client to send the heartbeat value to our handheld
        final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);
        nodes.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result) {
                final List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++) {
                        final Node node = nodes.get(i);
                        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), message, bytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Problem is I am only using one messageReceived method on the mobile. So I cant differentiate from the step value coming in or the heartrate value coming in.

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "received a message from wear: " + messageEvent.getPath());
        if (messageEvent.getPath().contains("HEARTBEAT")){
            // save the new heartbeat value
            currentValue = Integer.parseInt(messageEvent.getPath());
            if(handler!=null) {
                // if a handler is registered, send the value as new message
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "received a heartbeat message from wear: " + messageEvent.getPath());
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(currentValue);
            }
        }
        else {
            // save the new steps value
            currentStepValue = Integer.parseInt(messageEvent.getPath());
            if (handler != null) {
                // if a handler is registered, send the value as new message
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "received a step message from wear: " + messageEvent.getPath());
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(currentStepValue);
            }
        }
```

I tried passing in a byte array into the Heartrate sendMessage() and other strings as flags so that I could tell the values apart but no luck. Anyone know what the best way to go about this would be?

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are sending the data inside the path attribute. This is not the correct use of this parameter.

Let's take a look at the [`MessageApi.sendMessage(GoogleApiClient client, String nodeId, String path, byte[] data`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html#sendMessage(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20byte[])) method.

What you want to do is use `String path` to provide identifier for your message, for example in your case it would be `step_counter` and `heartbeat`. This way you can identify it on the other side, when you receive the message.

The sensor data should go into `data` field. You can put it raw there, but a better way is to create a `DataMap` and then serialize it into `byte[]`. This way you can enrich the data later easily.

Comment: Thanks very much gruszczy, that actually makes sense now. That's exactly what I need to do, how would you go about accessing the data map on the mobile side? For example, do I use messageEvent.getData()?

Comment: This is what you are looking around: `DataMap.fromByteArray(messageEvent.getData());`. Poke around the API and read what various methods do. Even if you don't understand everything, it will give you an overview and make it easier to look for answers later.

Comment: Perfect! Will do. Thanks again gruszczy. Much appreciated